# Copy text and find corresponding match to insert in another table [postgreql]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to migrate an existint text field into a many-to-many relationship.

```
offer
    id       work_days (text)
    45       night-and-weekend
    46       night-and-weekend
    47       full-week
    48       night-and-weekend
```

```
work_days
    id       work_days (text)
    1        full-week
    2        night-and-weekend
```

I would like to insert in `offer_work_days` the correspondences to have this result

```
offer_work_days
    offer_id    work_days_id
    45          2
    46          2
    47          1
    48          2
```

How can I achieve this with sql (on postgres)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GH5gJJaY)

You have to `JOIN` the tables on the `text` column, return only the `id` columns and insert the result into your new table.

```
INSERT INTO offer_work_days

SELECT o.id, w.id
FROM offer o
JOIN work_days w
ON o.work_days = w.work_days
```